# HoloLens using Geolocator

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

Does anyone have experience with this?
Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync() prompts the user to give permission to use location. Does the HoloLens have this user prompt capability for location access? Another tricky component is that the documentation also states that this must be called on the UI Thread.

```
#if WINDOWS_UWP
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
#endif

public class AccessPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void GetPosition()
    {
#if WINDOWS_UWP
        AsyncGetPosition();
#endif
    }

#if WINDOWS_UWP
    public async void AsyncGetPosition()
    {
        Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync().GetResults();
    }
#endif
}
```

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Assembly-CSharp.dll
Unhandled 'Platform.COMException' exception caught! - 'A method was called at an unexpected time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the Hololens doesn't have a built-in GPS.  You'd have to connect to one over bluetooth or wifi.